# Scrolling Default UINavigationBar results hideTheNavBar in Another UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm doing a ScrollToTop functionality in my app(like Instagram), i'm Using Default uinavigationbar in my app,

To Achieve this i used the below method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    //Initializing the views and the new frame sizes.
    UINavigationBar *navbar =self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    UIView *tableView = self.view;
    CGRect navBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

    CGRect tableFrame = self.view.frame;

    //changing the origin.y based on the current scroll view.
    //Adding +20 for the Status Bar since the offset is tied into that.

    //if (isiOS7)
    //{
        navBarFrame.origin.y = MIN(0, MAX(-64, (sender.contentOffset.y * -1)))  +20 ;
        tableFrame.origin.y = navBarFrame.origin.y + navBarFrame.size.height;

    //}else{
       // navBarFrame.origin.y = MIN(0, (sender.contentOffset.y * -1)) +20;
       // tableFrame.origin.y = MIN(0,MAX(-44,(sender.contentOffset.y * -1))) ;
    //}

    navbar.frame = navBarFrame;
    tableView.frame = tableFrame;
}
```

Now the Issue is, when i use this method, it's perfectly fine in current ViewController(Ctrl A)

Step 1:Scrolling my UIScrollView Or UITableView in Ctrl A(Default NavBar hidden in Ctrl A)

Step 2:Now i'm pushing or presenting another ViewController(Ctrl B)

Result: Default NavBar in Ctrl B goes Hidden(Empty Black Space)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The `UINavigationBar` is shared across all view controllers inside a navigation controller. So you'd want to add a call to reset the nav bar's frame to its original value inside `viewDidAppear:` of each view controller.

Rather than writing this on your own, you can use an open source project like TLYShyNavBar https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar

Answer (score 0):

Here is also awesome custom class which i used in my app with tableview.
https://github.com/inamiy/YIFullScreenScroll

Its hiding also your bottom bar if needed. You can also customize it.

```
self.fullScreenScroll = [[YIFullScreenScroll alloc] initWithViewController:self scrollView:tblView style:YIFullScreenScrollStyleFacebook];
self.fullScreenScroll.shouldHideTabBarOnScroll = NO;//Hiding bottom bar
```

There are also more customized option if you want to use.